# redirect doesn't work

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-mobile

I’m building a jquery mobile version of my site using CodeIgniter.
But I have a problem with the redirects.

E.g :
I am on the page « listComment »and I want to add a comment.
When I add it, the function « AddComment » is launched and in this
function I am redirected to « listComment ».
But I don’t know why I am on the page : www.mysite.com/mycontroller/AddComment
and not www.mysite.com/mycontroller/listComment.
I can’t see my comment added and if I refresh I have a lot of error
because I am not on the good page.

I really hope someone can help me, I don’t understand why redirect doesn’t
work on my Iphone, it works when I try the mobile version on my computer.

Here the code that I use, but I do not know where is the trouble because the code works fine on my computer :

```
<?php     function add_comment_unite()
{
    $data['users_online'] = $this->get_users_online();
    $data['uniteName'] = $this->uniteName();
    $data['numberInvit'] = $this->numberInvit();
    $data['friends'] = $this->get_friends_unite();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('texte_comment_unite','Commentaire','trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $texte_comment_unite = $this->input->post('texte_comment_unite');
        $id_space_unite = $this->input->post('id_news_u');
        $id_membre = $this->session->userdata('id_membre');
        $id_unite = $this->session->userdata('id_unite');

        $data = array(
            'texte_comment_unite'=>$this->input->post('texte_comment_unite'),
            'id_space_unite'=>$this->input->post('id_news_u'),
            'id_membre'=>$this->session->userdata('id_membre'),
            'id_unite'=>$this->session->userdata('id_unite'),
        );

        $this->unite_model->add_comment_unite_model($data);

        redirect('unite/get_news_unite');
    }
    else
    {
        $data['friends'] = $this->get_friends_unite();
        $data['users_online'] = $this->get_users_online();
        $data['uniteName'] = $this->uniteName();
        $data['numberInvit'] = $this->numberInvit();

        $layout_network['contenu'] = $this->load->view('espace_unite', $data, TRUE);
        $this->load->view('layout_network',$layout_network);
    }   
} ?>
```

In my view when I submit the form, I call this function.

Thank you

Comment: showing some code MIGHT help....  Help us Help you..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
 redirect('unite/get_news_unite', 'refresh');
```